# Querying mongoDb using pymongo with variable values

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

Consider the have the following collection:

```
db.collection.insert({id:1, value:1})
db.collection.insert({id:2, value:2})
db.collection.insert({id:3, value:3})
```

Now, I have a file which has a list of ids. I can read the file and store the id in a variable. How do I now query the collection to get the details  of that particular id:

```
f=open("file.txt")
for line in f:
  idTemp=line.strip()
  db.collection.find_one({"id":idTemp}) #This does not work
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`id` is an int, but anything read directly from a file is a string. Convert it to int first:

```
idTemp = int(line.strip())
```

Comment: Can you help me with this, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37707033/mongo-query-in-python-if-i-use-variable-as-value